# How do I solve this error in Laravel methodNotAllowed(array('POST'))?

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

I have this form that has a textarea. I should get the message typed and display the contents. However, I am getting this error `MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:`  I can not think of a way to solve it. I have tried with put but getting the same line error.

Below is my code
My blade:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="sendbulk"> 
{{ csrf_field() }}
<div class="form-group">
<label for="message" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Message</label>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message" required placeholder="Message"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1">
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">

<a href="/sendsms" class="btn btn-default pull-left">
<i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Cancel </a>
</div>
</div>  
</form>
```

My routes:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/receipts', 'HomeController@receipt');
Route::post('sendreceipt/{id}','HomeController@setReceipt');
Route::get('/sendsms', 'SmsController@send');
Route::post('/sendbulk', 'SmsController@sendsms');
Route::post('/selectContacts','SmsController@SelectContacts');
Route::get('/registerUsers', 'UsersController@Register');
Route::get('/companyprofile', 'UsersController@Company');  
Route::post('/companyProfile', 'UsersController@companyProfile');
Route::get('/view-most-valuable-customers', 'HomeController@valuable');

Route::get('users', ['as' => 'UsersController', 'uses' => 'UsersController@getIndex']);
Route::get('users-data', ['as' => 'UsersControllerUsersData', 'uses' => 'UsersController@Users']);

Route::get('/settings', 'SettingsController@index');
Route::get('/admin', 'adminController@dashboard');

Route::get('payments', ['as' => 'HomeController', 'uses' => 'HomeController@getIndex']);
Route::get('payments-data', ['as' => 'HomeControllerPaymentsData', 'uses' => 'HomeController@Payments']);

Route::get('sms', ['as' => 'SmsController', 'uses' => 'SmsController@getIndex']);
Route::get('Sms-data', ['as' => 'SmsControllerSmsData', 'uses' => 'SmsController@Sms']);

Route::get('logs', ['as' => 'LogsController', 'uses' => 'LogsController@getIndex']);
Route::get('Logs-data', ['as' => 'LogsControllerLogsData', 'uses' => 'LogsController@logs']);
```

My controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator,Auth, DB;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Yajra\Datatables\Facades\Datatables;
class SmsController extends Controller
{
/**
* Create a new controller instance.
*
* @return void
*/
public function __construct()
{
$this->middleware('auth');
}

public function sendsms(Request $request){

$message=$request->messsage;

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
'messsage' => 'required|max:160',]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
return redirect('/selectContacts')
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();}

echo $message;    
}
}
```

Would someone kindly point to me why I am getting this error?
Error:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

    in RouteCollection.php line 218
    at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 205
    at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 158
    at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 755
    at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 610
    at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 596
    at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 267
    at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
```

Comment: Hi @MarcBrillault.  No, everything is at its default position. resources/views...

Comment: It seems the form action is relative, so unless the current uri is ```/```, the URL will be wrong. Can you try adding a slash in the form action ?

Comment: Hello @SteveChamaillard I did try that but still getting the same error. I am not sure what is wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Can you update your route to remove the first slash ?

```
Route::post('sendbulk', 'SmsController@sendsms');
```